# Calculating the mean for 2x2 row-column groups for a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that I'd like to take multiple means of and output a single Series/DataFrame for.

I'd like each mean to be grouped by a *2x2 slice* of the entire DataFrame.

An example of this would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0' : [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10], '1' : [2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   '2' : [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]}).T

df_mean

2.75
3
4
5
.
.
5.75
7.25
```

The way it would group would be by taking the first rows 2x2 'slice' `([4, 5], [2, 0])` calculate the mean `(4+5+2+0)/4 = 2.75`, then repeat this for every slice until the next row until all possible 2x2 slices have been calculated over all rows.

Ie:

```
([5, 6], [0, 1]).mean() = 3
([6, 7], [1, 2]).mean() = 4
.
.
.
([3, 4], [10, 12]).mean() = 7.25
```

I'm only able to figure out how to groupby 2 down row-wise and take the mean:

```
df_mean = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2).mean()
```

But this only groups by 2 down each column rather than a 2x2 'cell'.

Is there a way to use groupby to do this? I'm trying to avoid computationally costly for-loops over both row and column indices if possible.

Comment: You might be able to do something with [pandas rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), it allows for windows along either axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `rolling`, `mean` and `dropna` along the two axis in order to have the result you want:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'0': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10], '1': [2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], '2': [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]}
).T
mean_df = (
    df.rolling(2)
    .mean()
    .dropna(how='all')
    .rolling(2, axis='columns')
    .mean()
    .dropna(how='all', axis='columns')
)
print(mean_df)
```

---

```
      1     2     3     4     5
1  2.75  3.00  4.00  5.00  6.25
2  2.00  2.75  4.25  5.75  7.25
```

Rolling create the windows on which the mean is computed, dropna deletes the rows where there are `NaN` values when the windows takes values outside the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If your all your data is of the same type, you can use `as_strided`:

```
size = (2,2)

from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

strides = df.values.strides

new_rows = (df.shape[0] - size[0] + 1) 
new_cols = (df.shape[1] - size[1] + 1)

array = as_strided(df.values, 
                   (size[0],size[1], new_rows, new_cols), 
                   [strides[0], strides[1], strides[0], strides[1]])

np.mean(array,
        axis=(0,1))
```

Output:

```
array([[2.75, 3.  , 4.  , 5.  , 6.25],
   [2.  , 2.75, 4.25, 5.75, 7.25]])
```